# How to tell if a log series converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have the following series.

$$(-1)^n \times \ln\Bigg(\frac{8n+5}{7n+3}\Bigg)$$

I tried the root, ratio and integral tests, but am doing something wrong because I am unable to tell if this series converges.

Comment: $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Use the [nth term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

First consider the inside fraction.  What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg( \frac{8n+5}{7n+3} \Bigg)$? Given this, what is the asymptotic behavior when the natural log is applied?

Comment: Applying this to the absolute value of the series, and seeing that this fraction converges to $\frac{8}{7}$, this series is divergent?

Comment: Indeed.  In particular, given some $\epsilon > 0$, the $n^{th}$ term will be within $\epsilon$ distance of either $\ln{\frac{8}{7}}$ or $-\ln{\frac{8}{7}}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  So the sequence doesn't limit to $0$.

Comment: Oh, I should add that the integral test wouldn't apply here since that test requires the series be strictly monotonic beyond a certain point.

Comment: Is applying a convergence/divergence test to the input of a function and then working your way outwards a general rule?

Comment: @user165293, Kaj is applying continuity of $\ln(x)$ here.

Comment: It should also be noted that $\ln(x)$ is not decreasing, which is something else you need to check for convergence.

Comment: @Nameless, that's true in the case, but not always.  If the inside was limiting to $1$, for example, then $\ln(\textbf{stuff}) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @KajHansen, which point are you replying to?

Comment: The very last @Nameless.

Comment: Oh no, I was implying both conditions needs to hold. As you have shown that one condition had already failed, the other didn't matter as much but shouldn't be neglected for the OP's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a large value of $n$, rewrite $$ \ln\Bigg(\frac{8n+5}{7n+3}\Bigg)=\ln(8n+5)-\ln(7n+3)=\ln(8n)+\ln\Big(1+\frac{5}{8n}\Big)-\ln(7n)-\ln\Big(1+\frac{3}{7n}\Big)$$ $$ \ln\Bigg(\frac{8n+5}{7n+3}\Bigg)=\ln\Big(\frac{8}{7}\Big)+\ln\Big(1+\frac{5}{8n}\Big)-\ln\Big(1+\frac{3}{7n}\Big)$$ Now, consider, for small values of $y$, the Taylor series $$\ln(1+y) \simeq \frac{y}{1}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}$$ replace $y=\frac{5}{8n}$ in the first logarithm and $y=\frac{3}{7n}$ in the second logarithm. You will end with $$ \ln\Bigg(\frac{8n+5}{7n+3}\Bigg)= \log \left(\frac{8}{7}\right)+\frac{11}{56 n}-\frac{649}{6272
   n^2}+\frac{29051}{526848 n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$

Applying the same approach to the most general case, you could find that $$ \ln\Bigg(\frac{an+b}{cn+d}\Bigg)= \log \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+\frac{\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}}{n}+\frac{\frac{d^2}{2
   c^2}-\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}}{n^2}+\frac{\frac{b^3}{3 a^3}-\frac{d^3}{3
   c^3}}{n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: @KajHansen. Thank you ! Cheers :)